# Missing Property Exception when calling java code from groovy with null parameters

Tags: java, groovy, junit, spock

I'm new to groovy and I'm trying to use Spock to do some integration tests.

I have a Java class `FunctionalTestCase` which I used as a framework before to do my tests.

For Spock, I'm still using this `FunctionalTestCase` from a groovy class. Most of the things worked without problems, but I have the following scenario:

In `FunctionalTestCase` I have something similar:

```
protected static void doSomething(@Nullable Object nullableObject)
{
    SomeInterface<InstrumentQuotationDataImage> marketDataSnapshot = new SomeInterface<InstrumentQuotationDataImage>()
    {
        @Override
        public InstrumentQuotationDataImage getData()
        {
            InstrumentQuotationDataImage instrumentQuotationData = new InstrumentQuotationDataImageImpl();
            if (nullableObject != null)
            {
                instrumentQuotationData.setDataRecord(nullableObject);
            }
            return instrumentQuotationData;
        }
    };
    marketData.getQuotationService().pushQuotation(marketDataSnapshot); 
}
```

This method is called once at setup with a non null parameter, and pushes an object into a Service (this can be seen at the end of the code).

When I later want to call `SomeInterface#getData` from the object retrieved from that `QuotationService`, instead of `nullableObject` to be `null` it throws `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException`.

Any idea why this happens from groovy? Using it from java everything works ok and the objects are `null`.

Comment: What's the actual exception?